# send image over TCP & save

Tags: python, image, file, save, tuples

I've build a program of client & server in TCP. The server screenshot its screen and send the image to the client . The problem begins when the client try to save this image in binary file. 
The only error the shows up is at the client side :

```
  data.save(path)

         TypeError: must be string or buffer, not tuple
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Thank and sorry for my poor English.

Server Code:

```
    from socket import *
    from PIL import Image
    import StringIO
    import ImageGrab


    port =9999

    print 'starting SERVER ... '
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(('', port)) # port to listen on

    print 'starting to listen...'
    sock.listen(SOMAXCONN)
    client, addr = sock.accept() # when accepting a connection, we get a tuple - two different                     variables with info about the new connection
    print 'done listening!'
    print 'client address is: ' + str(addr)


    buf=StringIO.StringIO()#create buffer    

    img=ImageGrab.grab()#take screenshot

    img.save(buf,format='PNG')#save screenshot to buffer

    client.sendall(buf.getvalue())

    sock.close()
    del sock
```

Client Code:

```
    import socket
    from PIL import Image

    mySocket =None
    ip='127.0.0.1'
    port=9999        
    try :
        print 'starting Client'
        mySocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        print 'trying to connet'
        mySocket.connect(( ip,port))
        print 'conneted successfuly!'
    except socket.error,msg :
        print 'Failed to create socket.Error code :' +str(msg[0])+'Error message:'+msg[1]

    data=mySocket.recvfrom(4096)

    path="D:\\Users\\user-pc\\Desktop\\bbbb.png"
    newf=open(path,'wb')
    newf.write(data)


    mySocket.close()
    del mySocket
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `data` is a tuple.

> The return value is a pair (string, address) where string is a string
>   representing the data received and address is the address of the
>   socket sending the data.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

So, you could do:

```
data, address = mySocket.recvfrom(4096)
```